# Prove that d(.;A) is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need help with the following proof, which my professor added for practice (but not as homework). I am completely lost here.

Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of a metric space $X$. Define $d(\cdot ,A) : X \to [0,\infty)$ by 
$$d(x,A) = \inf\{d(x,a) : a \in A\}.$$

Prove that $d(\cdot,A)$ is continuous.

Now there are some things that I do know.

1. The definition of continuous:Suppose X,Y are metric spaces, a ∈ X and f : X → Y. The function f is continuous at a if for every ε>0there is a δ>0such that if dX(a,x) < δ, then dY (f(a),f(x)) < ε. 
   If f is continuous at every point a ∈ X, then f is said to be continuous.
2. The following theorem:A function f : X → Y is continuous if and only if f−1(U) ⊂ X is open for every open set U ⊂ Y .

Comment: Hint: Show that $|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\le d(x,y)$.

Comment: I need more help than that, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it is uniformly continuous. It is easier to prove that.

Let $a\in A$. Then

$$d(x,A)\leq d(x,a)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,a)$$ (Why?) Think about the definition of $d(x,A)$ and the triangle inequality.

Thus we get $d(x,A)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,A)$. (Why?)

Can you continue from here?

Your aim is to show

$$|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\leq d(x,y)$$

hence one can always pick $\delta = \epsilon$.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome!